# evaluate expression in java

Tags: java, types

Could someone please help me with storing -1.0539727e+15 within java. I have never come across having to store such a number so have no idea what the best data type would be

Comment: It's `double` by default so I would use that unless you have additional requirements

Comment: @MGoksu: That's not what OP asked for; do you see a 30-digit number in the question?

Comment: ***FYI:*** From comments to [answer by ScottHunter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35414151/5221149), be aware that OP is really after evaluating the expression `30414870689655. - 8771520344379536`, even though the question text says nothing of it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for a `double`.

Comment: I have tried double, I had assumed it'd be a double, but I'm trying to parse it from a String which gives this exception 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30414870689655.-8771520344379536"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at try2.main(try2.java:34)

Comment: 30414870689655.-8771520344379536 is not *any* kind of number.

Comment: @JordanFrampton `-1.0539727e+15` is a valid `double` value. `30414870689655.-8771520344379536` is not a valid numeric value in any system.

Comment: That is what I thought, however the lecturer believes it is, so typing it into google returns -8.7411055e+15 which is the number I assume I need to get to

Comment: @JordanFrampton: That's not a *number*, it is an *expression* that evaluates to a number; parseDouble doesn't do evaluations.

Comment: @JordanFrampton `30414870689655 - 8771520344379536` is an *expression*, not a number. Evaluating the expression yields `-8741105473689881` aka `-8.741105473689881e+15`. If you need to evaluate expressions, look at [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/) or the built-in JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
    double d = 2e-6;
    double f = -1.0539727e15;
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(f);
    System.out.printf("d: %f\n", d);
    System.out.printf("f: %f\n", f);
```